# Unable to start docker container from arquillian cube on windows 10

Tags: docker, junit, jboss-arquillian

I have a junit test that have to start a docker container.
This is the code i use

```
 @ClassRule
public static ContainerDslRule mysql = new ContainerDslRule(TestConfigConstants.DOCKER_IMAGE)
        .withPortBinding(TestConfigConstants.PORT)
        .withEnvironment("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD", TestConfigConstants.PASSWORD,
                "MYSQL_DATABASE", TestConfigConstants.DB,
                "MYSQL_USER", TestConfigConstants.USERNAME,
                "MYSQL_PASSWORD", TestConfigConstants.PASSWORD);
```

When i start the test on a windows 7 pc with docker toolbox installed it's all ok. But when i start it on a windows 10 pc i have the follwing exception

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkField.get(FrameworkField.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getAnnotatedFieldValues(TestClass.java:230)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.classRules(ParentRunner.java:255)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.withClassRules(ParentRunner.java:244)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.classBlock(ParentRunner.java:194)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:362)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)  
Caused by: org.arquillian.spacelift.execution.ExecutionException: Execution of a task failed. Execution of a task failed. Unable to execute task SpawnProcessTask
    at org.arquillian.spacelift.execution.ExecutionException.prependMessage(ExecutionException.java:70)
    at org.arquillian.spacelift.execution.impl.FutureBasedExecution.unwrapException(FutureBasedExecution.java:173)
    at org.arquillian.spacelift.execution.impl.FutureBasedExecution.await(FutureBasedExecution.java:101)
    at org.arquillian.spacelift.task.os.ProcessBasedExecution.await(ProcessBasedExecution.java:149)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.util.CommandLineExecutor.execCommandAsArray(CommandLineExecutor.java:21)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.util.CommandLineExecutor.execCommand(CommandLineExecutor.java:13)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.util.AbstractCliInternetAddressResolver.getIp(AbstractCliInternetAddressResolver.java:29)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.util.AbstractCliInternetAddressResolver.ip(AbstractCliInternetAddressResolver.java:23)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.client.CubeDockerConfigurationResolver.resolveBoot2Docker(CubeDockerConfigurationResolver.java:317)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.client.CubeDockerConfigurationResolver.resolveServerIp(CubeDockerConfigurationResolver.java:209)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.impl.client.CubeDockerConfigurationResolver.resolve(CubeDockerConfigurationResolver.java:66)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.junit.rule.ContainerDslRule.initializeDockerClient(ContainerDslRule.java:74)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.junit.rule.ContainerDslRule.<init>(ContainerDslRule.java:50)
    at org.arquillian.cube.docker.junit.rule.ContainerDslRule.<init>(ContainerDslRule.java:44)
    at it.advansys.gestionalebdf.server.controller.contact.customer.CustomerContactControllerTest.<clinit>(CustomerContactControllerTest.java:66)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "boot2docker": CreateProcess error=2, Impossibile trovare il file specificato
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.arquillian.spacelift.task.os.SpawnProcessTask.process(SpawnProcessTask.java:107)
    at org.arquillian.spacelift.task.os.SpawnProcessTask.process(SpawnProcessTask.java:34)
    at org.arquillian.spacelift.task.Task.run(Task.java:98)
    at org.arquillian.spacelift.task.Task$1.call(Task.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Impossibile trovare il file specificato
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are something related with docker machine but not sure exactly the problem now,  how many docker machines do you have installed in that machine? If it is only one, can you try to start it manually (i.e docker-machine start dev)

If it works then there is a bug when docker-machine is not started yet.